# Blazor prevent POST actions for not authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor server and I would like to prevent users from making changes to app.
Some will have `writer` and some `reader` permissions.

I have "global"  component which is nice because I can do something like this:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.HAS_WRITE_PERMISSIONS">
    <Authorized>
        <DxButton SizeMode="SizeMode.Large" SubmitFormOnClick="true" Text="@(IsSaving ? "Saving...":"Save" )" Enabled="!IsSaving && !Disabled"></DxButton>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <br />
        <i> You are not authoried to make any changes</i>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsSaving { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

}
```

However this not prevent me from "clever" user how can insert button to any form (for example using Chrome developer tools) and hit `Save`.

I **don't want** to make special views just for reader persons and duplicate dozens of views. I would like to reuse same views (just prevent them to make any changes to data).

Is there any global `POST` actions interceptor in Blazor or anything "global".

I tried putting attribute to method but this does not work.

```
 [Authorize(Policy = Policies.HAS_WRITE_PERMISSIONS)]
        protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
```

EDIT:

I am not using httpClient to connect to backend (app will always be Blazor server, and never Blazor WebAssembly). I am connected "directly" to backend code.

EDIT2:

Ofcourse I could make `IdentityContext` which checks required roles using `AuthenticationStateProvider` and add that check to each Submit method but it is uglier than applying attribute or making some "global" solution.

```
 protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
        {
            if (await IdentityContext.HasWritePermissions() == false)
            {
                return;
            }
          ...
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense from an architectural point of view to add the authorization policies to a protected API and call that from the frontend or service layer, where you can respond to potential 403s accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to make architectural changes and use httpClient. App will always be Blazor server and it didn't wanted to complicate and use httpClient to make request on server while I am currently "on server"

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but why is the non authorized user even seeing the form they are not supposed to be able to submit.

Comment: Because, like said in question: there is user who can just see (reader) and user who has writter role (who is able to make destructive actions). I don't want complicate things, just simple, elegant solution. I don't want to make APIis, or make special "reader" views. Just hide submit button and prevent "clever" user from still submitting anything. This is not public app, only few users will use it. But I still want to make it secure, without introducing 2 weeks of development. Some DestructiveOperationDecorator that decorates all my destructive operations could  do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is too simple but have you thought about using a simple level of encapsulation?
Create a method that accepts a delegate of the operation that should happen if the user has the right privilege?

```
    public static class IdentiyContextExecuter
    {
        public static async Task<T> Execute<T>(Func<Task<T>> method, IdentityContext context)
        {
            if (await context.HasWritePermissions() == false)
            {
                return default;
            }

            T result = await method();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And in your submit method or in each submit method, you could use the class.

```
protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    var result = await IdentiyContextExecuter.Execute(() => Task.FromResult(true), IdentityContext);
}
```

It is not very elegant but should fit your purpose, I guess. You could rewrite it as an extension method for the IdentityContext class. Like `ExecuteIfHasWritePermissions(...)`

Comment: In fact, I already have some decorator for all my "destrcutive" actions. So I could add this authorize check at beginning of method